# Flutter: Could not generate a decorated class for type AppPlugin

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

#### Steps to reproduce

run flutter app in Android Studio.

#### Actual results

when I run the flutter app,I got the following errors:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for type AppPlugin.
         > com/android/builder/model/v2/ide/ProjectType
```

Environments:

1. OS : Windows11
2. Flutter: 3.10.6-statble
3. Android Studio: 2022.3.1

#### Logs

Logs

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/builder/model/v2/ide/ProjectType
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.inspectClass(ClassInspector.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.visitGraph(ClassInspector.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.inspect(ClassInspector.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator.inspectType(AbstractClassGenerator.java:274)
    at org.gradle.internal.instantiation.generator.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:214)
    ... 319 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.builder.model.v2.ide.ProjectType
    ... 324 more
```

##### more details

[full stacktrace](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/files/12273251/log.txt)

#### Flutter Doctor output

Doctor output

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.22621.2070], locale zh-CN)
    • Flutter version 3.10.6 on channel stable at D:\Dev\flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f468f3366c (4 weeks ago), 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
    • Engine revision cdbeda788a
    • Dart version 3.0.6
    • DevTools version 2.23.1
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at D:\Dev\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: D:\Dev\JetBrains\Toolbox\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at D:\Dev\JetBrains\Toolbox\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • M2007J17C (mobile) • 465614e4 • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Windows (desktop)  • windows  • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.22621.2070]
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 115.0.5790.171
    • Edge (web)         • edge     • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 115.0.1901.188

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

1.Nothing worked with reinstall Android Studio
2.Nothing worked with change flutter version